# Is it possible to provide a Name to a Dynamically created Struct (using Reflection) in Golang

Tags: go, struct, reflection, go-reflect, dynamic-struct

I've a dynamically created struct and I would like to provide a Name to this struct. Is it possible to do that?

```
// Test ...
type Test struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    structFields := []reflect.StructField{
        {
            Name: "Name",
            Type: reflect.TypeOf(""),
        },
    }
    // Provide a Name to this structDec 
    structDec := reflect.StructOf(structFields)

    fmt.Printf("\nType Dynamic : %+v\n", structDec)
    fmt.Printf("\nType Test : %+v\n", reflect.TypeOf(Test{}))
}
```

This prints

```
Type Dynamic : struct { Name string }

Type Test : main.Test
```

1. Is it possible to set a Name such as `Test1` to the Dynamic Struct `structDec`?
2. How does go derive the struct Name? I see during [dynamic struct creation](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/reflect/type.go#L2619) the `str` value (*which is the same value in the output*) is set in `reflect.structType`, Is this how the Name is calculated for Dynamic Struct's?

Go Playground : https://play.golang.org/p/8ra2pXZIHgp

Comment: Printf can also give you the typename: https://play.golang.org/p/QBhcGAn2bSn, what should answer Nr. 2. The answer to 1. is no, because that type is not availiable at compile time. You are creating this at runtime.

Comment: I'm not so sure about Number 2. Check the `Printf(%T)` it prints `reflect.Type` for both compiled and dynamic structs. https://play.golang.org/p/L61aA2io651 Yeah for No 1, I guessed the same. But looks like inside reflect.structOf they do try to figure out a name for the struct, its just no exposed to the developer.

Comment: `StructOf` creates an anonymous type. The type's name cannot be set.   The type's name matches the names of static anonymous types.  See https://play.golang.org/p/fcc9EhGOnEL.

Comment: @iLoveReflection hmm, I thought so. Any idea on how to get this Dynamic Struct working with Gorm? When I use this struct as a field in other structs then Gorm is unable to figure out the name, so falls back to empty string causing the DDL/DML statements to fail. I'm hitting a brick wall with all solutions, only option left is to write a DB Wrapper to handle these cases manually.